# Apache mod_rewrite Restful api

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm stuck on a problem with correct .htaccess in my restful webapp. My REST api code shall be accessible via the URL-pattern */api/** which should be redirected to *index.php* in the *api* folder.

All other URLs (except static files) shall be redirect to *index.html* in the root folder.

I have following folder structure:

```
- api
-- application/...
-- vendor/...
-- index.php
- public
-- css/...
-- js/...
- index.html
- .htaccess
```

And this is my .htaccess content:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# redirect all api calls to /api/index.php
RewriteCond "%{REQUEST_URI}" "^/api"
RewriteRule "^/api/(.+)$" "/api/index.php$" [QSA,L]

# If the request is a file, folder or symlink that exists, serve it up
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ - [S=1]

# otherwise, serve your index.html app
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /index.html [L]
```

I have tried to add another .htaccess to the api folder, to redirect the URLs with /api/* but without any success. So I tried to redirect it with a rule in the .htaccess above.

I think the lower to rules might be correct. Because the redirecting is working as expected. But the /api/ rule does not work. It seems that the requests also redirected to the index.html

What am I missing?

Comment: remove `$` from resulting path

Comment: I have some issue in Rest API, if i try -> abc.com/api/rest/products?limit=2 my site return 404 page error, how can i solve this and how can i get products using rest API   @Georg Leber

Comment: @Rathinam Please create a new question on SO to show your problem in more detail. This can have several issues, that can not be discussed in the comments (e.g. how is the server side mapping,...)

Comment: @GeorgLeber ye, someone already post regard this -> https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/246597/57334

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Minor tweaks of your regex pattern is what you need:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# redirect all api calls to /api/index.php
RewriteRule ^api/((?!index\.php$).+)$ api/index.php [L,NC]

# If the request is a file, folder or symlink that exists, serve it up
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# otherwise, serve your index.html app
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.html [L]
```

Comment: This also worked for my situation as well, where my bootstrapping PHP file was contained within the `/api` folder, but I've been struggling with getting the rewrite correct. I'm beginning to think the `DirectoryIndex` and explicitly looking to match `index.php` within the API rewrite was the secret sauce here. Thanks!

Comment: @anubhava I have some issue in Rest API, if i try -> abc.com/api/rest/products?limit=2 my site return 404 page error, how can i solve this and how can i get products using rest API

Comment: Someone already past, can u please help there https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/246597/57334

Comment: @anubhava zus was updated question like what i need exactly can you pls help me there?

Comment: @Rathinam: Looks like it is a magento config issue instead of mod_rewrite one. I have very little knowledge of magento unfortunately.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following set of rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/api/index\.php$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/api [NC]
RewriteRule ^api/.* /api/index.php$ [QSA,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l # to check for symbolic links
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L]

RewriteRule . - [L]
```